# Using pytest with Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pytest

My GAE app runs correctly on the local host (using `dev_appserver.py app`) and when deployed (`appcfg.py name update app/`)

However, when I run py.test on test code (in my app's directory), I get an import error:

```
app/main.py:4: in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import db
E   ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

GAE is installed here:
`/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/`
and it contains `google/appengine/ext/`

I have added the google-cloud-sdk to my $PATH, and there is a symlink in `/usr/local/` to GAE:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root       admin    google_appengine -> /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine
```

How can I get py.test to find google.appengine.ext?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/')
```

in your tests may work, but better use nosetests with [nose-gae](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NoseGAE) extension.

Answer (score 0):

You see the error because the Google App Engine SDK is not in your Python path.

You can manually interfere with `sys.path` at the beginning of your test scripts or package, use nose-gae extension or, you use something like (shameless plug - I wrote it) [testable_appengine](https://github.com/rbanffy/testable_appengine) to automate setting up a virtualenv with Google's SDK and some other nice things (like nose, without the nose-age plugins). It works seamlessly because, once you activate the virtualenv, the SDK is automatically added to your path.